# JavaScript: Replace element with content from another HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, pushstate

I would like to solve the following problem: Given a link on a Web page, I would like to replace the content of a specified `div` element with the content of a `div` element of another page. Say, just load the text "Stand on the shoulders of giants" from the Google Scholar page into my existing `div` element.

Up to date, if implemented the following example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<a href="http://www.whatsmyip.org/">Click me</a>

<div id="myid">Text to be replaced</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("a").click(function() {
      $.get(this.href, function(data) {
        $("#myid").replaceWith($(data).find("#fb-root"));
      });
      previous_page = location.href;
      window.history.pushState({page: $(this).index()}, $(this).html(), $(this).attr('href'));
      return false;
    });

    window.onpopstate = function(event) {
      location.reload();
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I've included `window.history` in order to change the URL in the location bar, and to allow the user to restore the previous state of the Web page without the new content.

Now, I have two issues:

- The replacement of the `<code>div</code>` element seems not to work, since the entire page from WhatIsMyIP is loaded.
- While using Chrome, the entire page gets reloaded again and again right from the beginning. I think, the event `window.onpopstate` is triggered continuously.

Thank for any help!

Comment: Maybe your pushState problem can be solved by use the plugin of that is mentioned in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210034/history-pushstate

Comment: I think that one source of the problem in your implementation is that "$.get" may take too much time for the event to be canceled. Thus, the "return false" may come too late. Anyone having seen that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could combine a `click` and a `$.load` on a hyperlink:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    $('#myid').load($(this).attr('href'));
    e.preventDefault(); //needed to prevent navigation!
});
```

If you want a special element within the page, you can append any selector. Example:

```
 $('#myid').load($(this).attr('href') + ' div');
```

This will append all divs of the requested page.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your first issue

Try this

```
$('#myid').load(this.href + ' #fb-root');
```

instead of this

```
$.get(this.href, function(data) {
    $("#myid").replaceWith($(data).find("#fb-root"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `event.preventDefault()` before `return false;`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, *you just want to replace the content of a specified div element on page1 (in this case div element with ID "myid") with the content of a div element from page2 (page2 is http://www.whatsmyip.org/)*.

Hope this might help:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<a href="http://www.whatsmyip.org/">Click me</a>

<div id="myid">Text to be replaced</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("a").click(function() {
  $.get(this.href, function(data) {
    var target_element_id_page2 = "element_id_page2";
    var target_element_type_page2 = "div";
    var respond= $('<div>' + data + '</div>');//You forgot this... It won't work unless you use it...
    var target_element = respond.find( target_element_type_page2 + '#'+ target_element_id_page2 )[0]; //There "might" be more div elements with the same id: that's why you specify index
    var container = document.getElementById( "myid");
    container.innerHTML = target_element.innerText;
    }, "html");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I took out window.history.pushState and window.onpopstate to better answer your question without any errors these two codes might give. If you put these back it should work perfectly. Althought I do not understand why you're using " previous_page = location.href; ". previous_page is not declared and you are not using it afterwards. Correct me if I am wrong...