# History API and jQuery not working

Tags: jquery, browser-history, pushstate, popstate

I'm trying to load a div into my page when an internal link is pressed and push a history state so that the location changes. I'm also trying to get the page to load the previous div on popstate. I can't seem to get anything working, not even the return false but I know that jQuery is being included since I can use it on another part of my page. Does anyone know what could be wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a:not([href^='http://'])").click(function() {
        history.pushState({ path: this.path }, '', this.href);
        $('#innercontents').load(location.pathname + ' #innercontents');
        return false;
    });
    $(window).bind('popstate', function() {
        $('#innercontents').load(location.pathname + ' #innercontents');
    });
});
```

Comment: Any errors in the JavaScript console (press F12)?

Comment: What exactly can't you get working?

Comment: The code is completely disregarded. Everytime I click a link it just goes straight to the link location like it normally would.

Comment: I would suggest that you take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5223689/28004).