# history.pushState with back and forward buttons

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, jquery

I need to make back and forward buttons working with this ajax method
This code working good and the URL on browser changing as it should be
but when you click on back and forward buttons, nothing happening

```
(function(){

    function clickNav(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        history.pushState(null, null, href);

        $.ajax({
            url: href,
            dataType: 'html',
            cache: false
        }).done(function(html){
            var $html = $(html);

            $('title').html($html.filter('title').text());
            $('#content').replaceWith($html.find('#content'));
            $('#nav').replaceWith($html.find('#nav'));

            $('#nav li a').on('click',clickNav);
        });

    }
    $('#nav li a').on('click',clickNav);

})();
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onpopstate

Answer (score 1):

I had to deal with this today. The following works for me (tested on four browsers in Win 7 so far)...

```
//CHECK FOR ADDRESS BAR CHANGE EVERY 500ms
var wwcint = window.setInterval(function(){
    if(window.last_location_href == undefined) {
        window.last_location_href = document.location.href;
    } else if(window.last_location_href != document.location.href) {
        window.last_location_href = document.location.href;

        //DO WHATEVER YOU NEED TO DO TO LOAD THE CORRECT CONTENT
        someFunctionToLoadTheContent(document.location.href);
    }
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

it is because your history is empty. For this you need to use

```
 history.pushState();
```

After that my buttons start working

Comment: Nope, not working and the URL on browser stop changing to the new URL

Comment: have a look over there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210034/history-pushstate   I think you will find an answer.