# Adding criteria to Django DRF responsive map InBBoxFilter with viewsets.py, not views.py?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, geodjango

We've developed a responsive map using [this tutorial](https://www.paulox.net/2021/07/19/maps-with-django-part-2-geodjango-postgis-and-leaflet/#adding-the-marker-viewset) where Django Rest Framework serves responses that populates the map. My viewsets.py:

```py
class MarkerViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """Marker view set."""

    bbox_filter_field = "geom"
    filter_backends = (filters.InBBoxFilter,)
    queryset = Tablename.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MarkerSerializer
    pagination_class = GeoPaginator
```

I'd like to add optional criteria to this filter if they are found in a GET value. The rest of my project uses views.py, which filters things differently. My simplified views.py which does this for something else:

```py
def EgFilterView(request):
    qs = Tablename.objects.all()
    date_min_query = request.GET.get('dmin')

    min_date = 1970

    qs = qs.filter(date__gte=dt.datetime(int(date_min_query), 1, 1, tzinfo=pytz.UTC))

    context = {
        'queryset': qs,
        'dmin': min_date,
    }

    return render(request, "main_page.html", context)
```

But it looks like viewsets.py doesn't handle `.get()` values in this way, but instead uses `.list()` and `.create()`, which I don't understand.

How can I include additional filters into my viewsets.py to further filter things with GET values? Would it be better to attempt to convert this viewsets.py / other complicated API stuff I don't understand into views.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out through other SO threads and the help of kind people over [in the Django Forums](https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/additionally-filtering-django-map-by-other-criteria-with-viewsets-py-if-found-in-get-value/11582).

We first need to make the request include the GET values. If following [this tutorial where the request URL is constructed in JS](https://www.paulox.net/2021/07/19/maps-with-django-part-2-geodjango-postgis-and-leaflet/#rendering-markers-incrementally) through:

```js
const markers_url = `/api/markers/?in_bbox=${map.getBounds().toBBoxString()}`
```

We need to add a string of the other inputs and their values:

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#theForm'); // supply ID of form containing inputs
var object = Object.values(form).reduce((obj,field) => { obj[field.name] = field.value; return obj }, {});  // get an object of all inputs and values https://stackoverflow.com/a/47188324
delete object[""]; // remove empty string we couldn't figure out cause of
const markers_url = `/api/markers/?in_bbox=${map.getBounds().toBBoxString()}` + '&' + new URLSearchParams(object).toString() // make this object a string in URLSearchParams format and suffix to url
```

Now we need to make viewsets.py filter the queryset with these GET values. We can do this by [overriding the `filter_queryset(self, queryset)` method](https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/additionally-filtering-django-map-by-other-criteria-with-viewsets-py-if-found-in-get-value/11582/15):

```py
class MarkerViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """Marker view set."""
    bbox_filter_field = "geom"
    filter_backends = (filters.InBBoxFilter,)
    queryset = Tablename.objects.all()

    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        queryset = super().filter_queryset(queryset)
        extra_field1 = self.request.query_params.get('extra_field1') # creates string of the GET param "extra_field1"
        if extra_field1:
            queryset = queryset.filter(extra_field1=extra_field1) # filter here as desired
        return queryset

    serializer_class = MarkerSerializer
    pagination_class = GeoPaginator
```