# JS - window.location and keeping current path

Tags: javascript

I wish to simulate clicking on a link and redirecting using js, i do this with:

```
window.location
```

But how can I keep the current path:

```
mysite.com/article/page
```

And go to:

```
mysite.com/article/page/some-js-var
```

I know I can do:

```
window.href+'/'+myVar
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: HTML 5 history API is the way, [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210034/history-pushstate)

Comment: I know you didnt ask but if you become to solution make your personal router on the client-side then i think you probably should look at backbone or angular js

Comment: You want to preserve the link in the address bar and want to show the user a different page?

Comment: I just want to get the link that's in the address bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives you the exact `url` the user is on:

```
document.location.href
```

Comment: Is this what you want/